# pandas extract common substring from 1 column based on conditions in another column

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
code    description          col3        col4
123456  nice shoes size4     something   something
123456  nice shoes size5     something   something
567890  boots size 1         something   something
567890  boots size 2         something   something
567890  boots size 3         something   something
234567 baby overall 2yrs     something.  something
234567 baby overall 3-4yrs     something  something
456778 shirt m     Something.   Something
456778 shirt l     something    Something
456778 shirt xl    Something   Something
```

I like to shorten 'description' to be the common substring based on similar 'code' column. and drop duplicates.

```
code    description          col3        col4
123456  nice shoes          something   something
567890  boots               something   something
234567 baby overall    something    something
456778 shirt              Something   Something
```

I Suspect need to groupby and maybe apply a function but not able to get my head round this. 
Found a function but that takes in 2 strings. Not sure if it
could be of help. And this function only takes 2 strings whereas my data may have 5 rows having same code...

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

string1 = "apple pie available"
string2 = "come have some apple pies"

def extract_common(string1, string2):
    match = SequenceMatcher(None, string1, string2).find_longest_match(0, len(string1), 0, len(string2))

    print(match)  # -> Match(a=0, b=15, size=9)
    print(string1[match.a: match.a + match.size])  # -> apple pie
    print(string2[match.b: match.b + match.size])  # -> apple pie
    return string1[match.a: match.a + match.size]
```

Appreciate any help rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need pandas **0.25.1** to use [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html)

```
mask=(df.groupby('code')['code'].transform('size')>1)
df1=df[mask]
df2=df[~mask]
s=df1.groupby('code',sort=False)['description'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x).split(' ')).explode()
s_not_duplicates=s.to_frame()[s.map(s.value_counts()>1)].drop_duplicates().groupby(level=0)['description'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
description_not_duplicates=pd.concat([s_not_duplicates,df2.description])
print(description_not_duplicates)
```

---

```
123456      nice shoes
234567    baby overall
456778           shirt
567890      boots size
Name: description, dtype: object
```

Comment: Sorry, i think dataset is not representative enough. Some rows may not have the size keyword. For apparel products sizes could be just an 'm' or kids apparels could be 2 - 3 yrs example.

Comment: Would love to have a solution, any ideas anyone else?

Comment: Depending on how your data frame is, you could update it to be representative enough

Comment: I don't know what the criteria for columns 3 and 4 would be. So I've excluded them